# How to change my character religion?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

My character is with pagan religion (Tengri) and I want to convert him to Orthodox Christianity? How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways for you to change religions. The first is to select the religion you wish to change to (use the Religious map mode, <kbd>R</kbd>), and hit the "Convert" button. This has a piety cost based on a number of factors (mostly how similar the religions are to one-another, but factors like whether it's been reformed are also factors).

[image]

[image]

The other option is to adopt the religion of a spouse or concubine. This is "free", but you do need to be married in the first place, which can be dicey, especially if the religion you're hoping to convert to is considered "evil" in the eyes of your current one, which can cause an opinion malus large enough to prevent marriage in the first place.

Once you're legally tied to your heretical partner, simply choose "Adopt Faith" from the interaction menu.

[image]

Comment: For underage heirs, you can assign a Ward and ask the ward to convert your heir. Although it's not strictly "your character" at that point in time, it will likely be "you" somewhere in the future.

Comment: Another option is that when you are being attacked in a Holy War, then there is a decision available to end the war by converting to the religion of the attacker. But that's of course very situational.

Comment: Lol I've just noticed it doesn't logically make much sense to require you to be very pious in order to be able to change religion. In-universe, if you managed to acquire so much faith, you would (usually) be _less_ likely to do such a thing…